# Highstock: Change color of date input box border if active

Tags: css, input, highcharts

There seems to be an default blue color for the active state border color of the date input box. Do I need to control this color through CSS? I couldn't find the option under *rangeSelector*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs are rendered as shapes in SVG, not input forms. So yoo need to wrap highcharts function and define it.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian. Where and how can I do that?

Comment: [how to wrap](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts) and drawInput function in the [code](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js)